Girl seeking to avenge death of her parents
The movie starts off with this girl who has a plan to get revenge for her dead parents. She mostly succeeds, but is left with this other female fighter who later reunites with the sister. 
There was this one particular scene where the sister was out picking up a cake for the big sister's (main girl) birthday, but was followed by bad guys who want her dead. Calling her older sister for assistance to get out of this situation, the older sister finds routes for her sister to escape. But while helping her the bad guys storm her house and eventually kill her. When the little sister came home to find her sister dead, she seeks out to finish her older sister's plan to get revenge for her parents and older sister. 
I think this film was either Chinese or Korean. 

Movies & TV Stack Exchange has strict rules about providing sufficient detail in "Identify this movie/show" questions. We're going to need to know what kind of cake it was.

Though the questions are a bit different, I'm pretty sure you're after So Close, so I marked it as a duplicate. It contains the cake scene you described.

@Walt Is that fair play when the other question wasn't confirmed as answered?

@faintsignal Well, it let me do it, so I guess it is. Also, it seems the OP there did say it was the right answer a year later, but posted the comment as an answer and under a different account (it's in the deleted answers).

@Fair enough. Might be useful to quote the acknowledgement from the OP of that question in a comment on the answer for "closure".

@ faintsignal " what kind of cake it was" lol
